# C# how to combine 2 Task<IEnumerable<T>> via Union and return task

Tags: c#, linq, asynchronous, async-await

Right now I have 2 `Task<IEnumerable<T>>`, call them TaskA and TaskB.  I need to pass along a TaskC to an async method.  In that method, it is awaited and the resulting IEnumerable is operated on, and I can't change that method.

What I want to do is somehow say "when TaskC is awaited, then await TaskA, and UNION those results with the awaited result of TaskB".

If the IEnumerables weren't wrapped in Tasks, of course I would just do:

`var ResultC = ResultA.Union(ResultB);`

How can I accomplish this while still lazily evaluating TaskA and TaskB?

Answer (score 7):

> If the `IEnumerables` weren't wrapped in `Task`s, of course I would just do:

```
var ResultC = ResultA.Union(ResultB);
```

> How can I accomplish this while still lazily evaluating TaskA and TaskB?

Remember that `await TaskA` is the operation which both *asynchronously waits* for the task to complete *and extracts its resulting value*.  So you can simply say:

```
Task<IEnumerable<T>> resultA = whatever;
Task<IEnumerable<T>> resultB = whatever;
Func<Task<IEnumerable<T>>> getTaskC = 
  async () => (await resultA).Union(await resultB); 
Task<IEnumerable<T>> resultC = getTaskC();
```

And now you have a task in hand that represents the workflow of "asynchronously wait for A and B, and then take their union".

Comment: Considering the code of this answer, be careful to not replace `whatever` in the lambda: `async () => (await whateverA).Union(await whateverB)`. This will cause the serialization of the execution of the two tasks.

Comment: Searched all over the web. This was the best answer for concatenating two IEnumerables in an async approach. Wonder why there is so less articles on this common scenario

Answer (score 1):

Await both with `WhenAll`, then take the union of the results.

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetUnion<T>(Task<IEnumerable<T>> a, Task<IEnumerable<T>> b)
{
    await Task.WhenAll(a,b);
    return a.Result.Union(b.Result);
}
```

And call it like this:

```
var results = await GetUnion(TaskA,TaskB);
```

Here is a working example on [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VEQIyr)

Comment: Can you say why it is necessary to use `WhenAll`?  Why would you not simply write `return (await a).Union(await b);` ?

Comment: I can see how this would function, but its not lazy enough.  In your example, `results` needs to be a Task<IEnumerable<T>>`, which I can pass onwards.  That is what I'm trying to figure out how to do.

Comment: @MAW74656: then just use `GetUnion(TaskA, TaskB)` if you want the task and not the result!

Comment: @EricLippert - Right, but if I do that, when will the `A.Result` or 'await A` occur?

Comment: I don't understand the question. It occurs when that code runs, which will be some arbitrary time after the `WhenAll` completes normally.  Calling `GetUnion` calls `WhenAll`; if `A` and `B` are both already done then `A.Result` is called and so on. If not, then the coroutine yields and resumes when `A` and `B` have completed normally.

Comment: @EricLippert - When I do `var results = GetUnion(TaskA,TaskB)` as you suggest, I will have then a Task in results.  At that point: have the awaits already evaluated?  I'm trying to avoid evaluation of TaskA and TaskB until TaskC is called somewhere in the further method.

Comment: @MAW74656: Again I don't understand the question. What do you mean by "have the awaits already evaluated?"  When you call an async method, the method runs normally until it reaches the first `await` where the awaited task is not completed, and the coroutine yields at that point.

Comment: @MAW74656: Based on your question I suspect that you have an incorrect mental model of what `await` means.  It means "if the awaited task is complete, extract its value and continue; if it has not completed then sign up the remainder of this method as the continuation of the task and yield control back to my caller".  That's what it means to "evaluate an await expression".

Comment: @EricLippert - I don't even want to start the task until later, so it will never be complete when we hit the first await in the example.  So this doesn't meet the need here.

Comment: @MAW74656: Remember, an async method does one of four things when you call it: (1) goes into an infinite loop and never returns, (2) throws an exception, (3) awaits an incomplete task and suspends, returning an incomplete task, (4) returns a completed task.  Those are the only four things an async method can do!

Comment: @MAW74656: There is no such thing in C#'s implementation of async functions as a *task that is not started*. When you call an async method, the task you get back represents a *started* task.  Can you say how it is that you have obtained a task that is not started? That is possible in C#, but not by using `async` methods. It sounds like you don't want `Task<T>` at all. It sounds like you want `Lazy<T>`.

Comment: @EricLippert - That's what I have in the first place, before any of my changes... a TaskA that is passed into the other method and not evaluated until several other things are done.  The only difference I want to make is to Union TaskA with TaskB and still pass that on for evaluation later on.

Comment: @MAW74656: I still don't understand what you mean by a task being "evaluated".  Tasks are just tasks.  **Expressions** are things that are evaluated.

Comment: @EricLippert - I can make a task by going var tsk = new Task<int>(() => 1);  But nothing is happening at that point until I await the task (or Task.Run() or something similar).  The contents of the task, or its definition or whatever its called isn't evaluated until the await.  It sounds like your saying this is untrue?

Comment: @MAW74656: I see what you're getting at. Yes, using the Task constructor makes a "cold" task that doesn't start until you call `Start`.  But tasks created by `async` methods are always "hot" in C#. So in your example are tasks A and B already started? In general in C# it is not super easy to *prevent* a task from starting; we designed asynchronous workflows with the assumption that if you have a task, you want it to execute.

Comment: @EricLippert - No, they're not.  They don't get evaluated (or started if you prefer) until later in the other method they're passed to.

Comment: @MAW74656 So are you calling `Start` on those tasks?  If you're referring to tasks that you got by calling the constructor, then yes, you'd need to call `Start` for them to start doing work.  If you aren't calling `Start`, then the task is doing its work from the moment you have the task, and there's nothing you can do later to "start" it.

Comment: @Servy - No, the they are awaited later on.  No explicit Start is called.  I wonder if the original writers of the method thought they were saving that processing by doing it this way but were mistaken?

Comment: @MAW74656 awaiting a task doesn't start it, it just prevents the current method from doing anything until it finishes (without blocking the current thread, and instead adding a continuation to that task).  If you're just awaiting the task, then it has already started (or something else needs to start it for it to ever start), and the only thing changed by when you `await` it is what you decide to do before that task has finished.

Comment: @Servy - Then I have no idea why they bothered to pass in a Task at all.  It functions, but I may have erred assuming it was done well.

Comment: Without knowing either what your code actually does, or what it's supposed to do, none of us can really comment on that.

Comment: @Servy - I do understand that, and thank you.  It looks like I'm asking the wrong questions here.

Comment: @MAW74656: I think I finally get what you're asking; it took a long time to figure out because almost no one works with "cold" tasks because it is such a pain to do so! You'd normally only work with cold tasks **if you were writing a task scheduler**, and if you are, then I submit to you that (1) this is a job to be left to experts, and (2) there probably already is a task scheduler that meets your needs.

Comment: @EricLippert - I am not intentionally writing a scheduler, I'm simply modifying some existing code.  I don't believe scheduler is exactly what they're doing, but I believe they were trying to save running the task until some other checks were performed (so similar to a scheduler).  I agree, no reason to recreate the wheel for a scheduler.